# Allow anonymous access to controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I need to allow controller action for any user without login.

```
public class ItemController : Controller
    {
       public ActionResult WebGallery()
        {
           //code goes here
            return View("WebGallery");
        }
}
```

I tried the below code in my web.config but still redirected to the login page.

```
  <location path="~/Item/WebGallery">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I use forms authentication but does not use role base authentication so i can not use  `[Authorize]`

Comment: Use [AllowAnonymous] above your Controller class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modifying the location path attribute worked for me.

```
<location path="Item/WebGallery">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: Hmm not working for me. Not sure what I'm doing wrong :(

Answer (score -1):

The authorisation rule allowing '*' only covers logged-in users. For anonymous users, use '?' instead:

```
<location path="~/Item/WebGallery">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
           <allow users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Further information on ASP.NET authorisation rules can be found over on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx).

Comment: Do you have any other rules that may be being matched, that could be a higher priority?